# Find novel categories between groups

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I am trying to identify which trees are different between two groups `a` & `b` across different forest types (`type`).

My dummy example:

```
dd1 <- data.frame(
  type = rep(1, 5),
  grp = c('a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'),
  sp =  c('oak', 'beech', 'spruce',
          'oak', 'yew')
)

dd2 <- data.frame(
  type = rep(2, 3),
  grp = c('a', 'b', 'b'),
  sp =  c('oak', 'beech', 'spruce')
)


dd <- rbind(dd1, dd2)
```

I can find unique species by each group (in reality, two groups: type & grp) by  `distinct`:

```
dd %>% 
  group_by(type, grp) %>% 
  distinct(sp)
```

But instead I want to know which trees in group `b` are different from group `a`?

Expected output:

```
   type grp   sp    
  <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
1     1 b     yew    # here, only `yew` is a new one; `oak` was previously listed in group `a`
2     2 b     beech  # both beech and spruce are new compared to group `a` 
3     2 b     spruce
```

How can I do this? Thank you!

Comment: I am afraid I do not understand: beech and spruce is both in a and b, so why is it that they are in the expected output? Else you could use an anti_join: `dd |> anti_join(dd |> filter(grp == "a"), by = c("sp"))` or `setdiff(dd$sp[dd$grp == "b"], dd$sp[dd$grp == "a"])`.

Comment: good idea, I will try the antijoin! I need to find teh differences between individual groups and across `type`: e.g. difference between `a`, `b` for type 1, 2, etc... I have now added this into my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition to filter is

```r
library(dplyr)

dd %>%
  group_by(type) %>%
  filter(grp == 'b' & !sp %in% sp[grp == 'a']) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 × 3
#    type grp   sp    
#   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
# 1     1 b     yew   
# 2     2 b     beech 
# 3     2 b     spruce
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try an `anti_join`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd |>
  anti_join(dd |> filter(grp == "a"), by = c("sp", "type"))
```

Output:

```r
  type grp     sp
1    1   b    yew
2    2   b  beech
3    2   b spruce
```

Comment: Thank you @Harre, I really like this example! please, can yopu however explain how does the `}>` works? I have a bit troubles to find R description abouit it.. Thanks again foor your help!

Comment: `|>` is the "new" pipe in base R, in many ways similar to `%>%`. I.e. `dd |> filter(grp == "a")` == `filter(dd, grp == "a")` :)